# Unable to POST data to another controller then STORE in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and trying to submit a form on dropdown selection. Even though i can do it. But it always redirect to `store` function which is registered as a `resource` route.

My routes.php file have routes define like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

        Route::get('dashboard', function () {
            return view('dashboard.dashboard');
        });

        Route::get('getcurrency', 'QuoteController@getCurrency'); <!--------This is where i have problem--------->
        Route::resource('quotes','QuoteController');
    });

});
```

I tried naming route as well. But it always take me towards the `store function`

here is how my dropdown looks like:

```
<form method="post" action={{ action('QuoteController@getCurrency') }}>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-1">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-5">      
                                        <select class="form-control select2me selectCurrency" name="user_id" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                            @foreach($users as $user)
                                                <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{ $user->name }} 
                                                    @if(!empty($user->companyname))
                                                        ({{$user->companyname }})
                                                    @else
                                                        ({{$user->email}})
                                                    @endif
                                                </option> 
                                            @endforeach 
                                        </select>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
</form>
```

I am not able to understand why its always force send the value to `store` function only, when i have even try to mentioned `route`, `method`, `url` and `action`. Non of the system working for me.

Is laravel have predefined tendency to take SUBMIT BUTTON to a specific function only?

Here is what my URL is when i have my form :

http://localhost/laravel/public/quotes

Does anyone know why this happens? And how can i fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

        Route::get('dashboard', function () {
            return view('dashboard.dashboard');
        });

        Route::post('getcurrency', 'QuoteController@getCurrency'); // make it post instead of get
        Route::resource('quotes','QuoteController');
    });

});
```

blade file

```
<form method="post" action={{ url('getcurrency') }}>
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value={{ csrf_token() }}/>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-1">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-5">      
                                        <select class="form-control select2me selectCurrency" name="user_id" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                            @foreach($users as $user)
                                                <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{ $user->name }} 
                                                    @if(!empty($user->companyname))
                                                        ({{$user->companyname }})
                                                    @else
                                                        ({{$user->email}})
                                                    @endif
                                                </option> 
                                            @endforeach 
                                        </select>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Haseena, but it seems like i am not able to go to `getcurrency` function. Still going to `store`

Comment: Hey one more thing. I have form inside a form. Is that a reason?

Comment: can you try to use one form and check whether working properly ?

Comment: If you have two forms and two submit button, make one as submit button and one as normal button, and make the normal button submit through an ajax call.  It will be better. Don't try to use one form inside another.

Answer (score 0):

If you use route resource your post will go automatically in store method for more https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

If you want to change the method then change the action,like

```
<form method="post" action='quotes'>
```

Then need to write a route for this url before resource route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard.dashboard');
    });

    Route::get('getcurrency', 'QuoteController@getCurrency'); <!--------This is where i have problem--------->
    Route::post('quotes','QuoteController@customMethod');
    Route::resource('quotes','QuoteController');
});

});
```

Comment: Ok i tried your method. But its giving this error.  `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:` dont you think that it should be Route::post('getcurrency','QuoteController@ getCurrency');` instead of quotes?

Comment: in Route::post you need to use full url.Like if your form post url is (quotes/getcurrency) then your route will Route::post('quotes/getcurrency', 'QuoteController@ getCurrency')